# Alternate message when video src not found and custom error message of browser

Tags: html, angularjs, video, iframe

```html
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item col full-scr" type="text/html" src="{{aarti.url | trustAsResourceUrl}}"  frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

This show 404 error message i does not want to show this message .i want to show image or some text in place of this error message when src not found. i tried everything but not worked for me.. please tell what is it solution.

Answer (score 0):

To check the src of iframe exist or not we have to use ajax

Try this:

**Javascript:**

```
function urlExists(url, callback){
$.ajax({
 type: 'HEAD',
 url: url,
 success: function(){
   callback(true);
 },
 error: function() {
   callback(false);
 }
 });
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item col full-scr" type="text/html" src="{{aarti.url | trustAsResourceUrl}}"  frameborder="0" ng-if="urlExists(aarti.url)">

<p ng-if="!urlExists(aarti.url)" >Your error Message</p>
```

Comment: aarti.url.length display the same length in all cases.

Comment: same again in every condition !urlExists(aarti.url) is called.